# How to set value kendo multiselect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

My scenario is I want to select some informations with checkbox in my grid and I can get that values like array ["3001","3004"] but when i click button kendo multiselect cannot set my values

here is onclick function:

```
function ongrdfleetinvoice() {

var multiselect = $("#fleetinvoice").data('kendoMultiSelect');
multiselect.value(["3001","3004"]);

}
// I also try like this same function
function ongrdfleetinvoice() {

$("#fleetinvoice").getKendoMultiSelect().value(["3001","3004"]);

} 


//Here is my multiselect 
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect().Name("fleetinvoice")
                  .DataTextField("CariNam")
                  .DataValueField("CariKod")
                  .Placeholder("All")
                  .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
                  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 300px;" })
                  .DataSource(source =>
                  {
                      source.Read(read =>
                      {
                          read.Action("FillFleet", "HeadOffice");
                      });
                  })
                )

   //C# Code
   var resultCariler = (from m in objEntities.Cariler
                                 where (m.CariTip == 13)
                                 orderby m.CariNam ascending
                                 select m).AsQueryable();
            foreach (var item in resultCariler)
            {
                Cariler objCariler = new Cariler();
                objCariler.CariKod = item.CariKod.Trim();
                objCariler.CariNam = item.CariNam + - + item.CariKod.Trim();
                listCari.Add(objCariler);
            }
```

but it's not working.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Please add your html markup and script part where `kendoMultiSelect` initializes

Comment: It seems that your problem is not related to kendo as your example code works perfectly at their demo page

Comment: @MikhailNeofitov i added also html of multiselect yes i also checked demo but i dont understand why this is not working

Comment: @MikhailNeofitov I solve problem when i fill the multi select and grid that to are different values so this one giving a problem

Comment: good. As I wrote, it is not related to multiselect itself

Comment: Yes thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I realise something when i fill my grid and my multiselect in C# side the field names are equal but values are not equeal when i change of that and put same values.. It worked...

```
var resultCariler = (from m in objEntities.Cariler
                             where (m.CariTip == 13)
                             orderby m.CariNam ascending
                             select m).AsQueryable();
        foreach (var item in resultCariler)
        {
            Cariler objCariler = new Cariler();
            objCariler.CariKod = item.CariKod.Trim();
            objCariler.CariNam = item.CariNam + - + item.CariKod.Trim(); //I changed this part with same in grid
            listCari.Add(objCariler);
        }
```

TO

```
var resultCariler = (from m in objEntities.Cariler
                             where (m.CariTip == 13)
                             orderby m.CariNam ascending
                             select m).AsQueryable();
        foreach (var item in resultCariler)
        {
            Cariler objCariler = new Cariler();
            objCariler.CariKod = item.CariKod.Trim();
            objCariler.CariNam = item.CariNam;
            listCari.Add(objCariler);
        }
```